How to bet on individual games in best of seven series so that no matter how my team wins I make same profit? (Assume games are coin flips)
Suppose I have a 100 dollar starting bankroll. I want to bet this on my team to win a best of 7 series, however assume I am restricted to only being able to bet individual games one at a time as they occur, and money accumulates or subtracts from by bankroll after every game. Also assume that the chances of winning each game is 50% and each individual game bet pays 1:1. So for example, if I bet 20 dollars on game 1 and my team wins, I now have 120 dollars available to bet on the second game. If I lose I will only have 80 dollars available to bet on the second game. I want to know what betting strategy I should adopt (e.g. what percentage or amount from my bankroll should I bet on each game based on all previous games) so that no matter what happens, if my team wins the best of 7 series I will end up with the exact same amount of money (and if my team does not win the series, my bankroll will end up being 0).
I've tried to solve this question but the tricky parts for me are 1) the fact that the series might terminate after fewer than 7 games and 2) the fact that the amount of money I have available to wager in each game fluctuates based on the outcome of the previous game.
I assume in real life you can probably just bet on the outcomes of entire series, but this is just a purely theoretical problem I came up with in my head.

To start.with, from where have you got this question ?

I came up with it in my head. It has no practical value as far as I'm aware of

Everything that comes out of your head can not be cracked .

Your statement is correct. But it doesn't imply this particular thing out my head can't be cracked.

That is true, but I doubt very much that this one can be cracked.

Why do you think this?

It can be solved. First think about the case where there are 3 games instead of 7. Convince yourself that betting $50 in the first and second game works (if after the first two games each team won one, you are forced to bet everything, i.e. $100 in the last game, since you stipulated that you should have $0 left if your team loses the series).
So you are guaranteed to double your money if your team is the winner of a series of 3 games, and be left with $0 if they lose. Now you can use this plus similar ideas to deal with a series of more games.

This can be solved with backwards induction and is usually easiest to see when you draw out the tree of possible outcomes.
Let's denote the current state of the game by $S_{i,j}$ where $i$ is the number of games that your team has won and $j$ is the number of games that the other team has won.
We know that if at any point, the other team is one away from winning (i.e. $j=3$) then you must wager the full amount that you have since you wish to end with 0 if the opposing team wins the tournament. We can therefor conclude that your bankroll must be equal to your starting bankroll at the state $S_{3,3}$.
We can also see that your bankroll must be equal to your starting bankroll at any point $i=j$ (it's a tie in the series). This does NOT mean, however, that your wager amount is the same for all tie points. This is much easier to see with the visual diagram where each node shows what your bankroll should be at that state. The difference between the node and the two children nodes that it has is the wager amount needed at that state:


There's an upside-down Pascal's Triangle hidden in the diagram that gives part of the formula for the wager at each node. (The other part is a negative integer power of $2$.)

We can also observe from this that all we need to make this work is that the payout on the bet is $1:1$; the probability that your team wins does not matter in this scheme of betting.
